# Is Azure compatible with JPEG XR?

Tags: web-hosting, content, deployment, azure, jpeg

I just put an [F#/MVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3d2bf938-fc9e-403c-90b3-8de27dc23095) app into a Windows Azure solution as a Web Role. Before migration, my JPEG XR (`*.WDP\`) files were getting displayed on the client in IE9 without issue via my local and hosted sites. Now, after migration into Windows Azure, my JPEG XR files neither get displayed in my local Windows Azure compute emulator nor do they get displayed when they are deployed to `http://*.cloudapp.net`.

Is there some sort of conflict with Widows Azure and (JPEG XR) `*.wdp` files?  If so, what is the accepted best practice for overcoming this conflict?

Comment: UPDATE: This probably isn't a an issue with the Azure Servers.  It looks like a quirk with VS2010 or the Azure tools.  I **think** the *.WPD files aren't getting copied into my *.cspkg file.  I find this odd since I **think** I have the build action set to "Content".  I'm also having a similar prob. with some non-compiled *.fs and *.fsi files that I let users download as content.  I have also tried setting build action to "None" and adjusting "Copy to Output Directory" param as indicated by http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/01/28/adding-files-to-your-windows-azure-service-package.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't figured out an **easy** way to get the JPEG XR and downloadable F# code files to go into the `*.cspkg` file, but I did get the files to work on my Web Role. I had to follow Mr. Vipul Patel's instructions in his article [Using Windows Azure Storage Service to Upload Files](http://www.developer.com/net/using-windows-azure-storage-service-to-upload-files.html#comment_form) to create a storage service and then put the affected files in the blob.

Once the files were uploaded into the blob per Mr. Patel's instructions, I could easily verify their existence and my Web Role was able to access them via an absolute URL.

I'm still a bit dissapointed, however, that I had to go through this effort. When I code at home, I am a hobbyist on a budget so the added cost of having to create a storage service is not **necessarily** welcome as I learn skills that **may or may not** someday transfer to my day job.